# Question about simply connected components

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function whose range contains $\overline{D}$. Show that the components of $f^{-1}(D)$ are simply connected. ($D$ here is the open disk $D(0,1)$)

I don't even know how to start this question, I would like some suggestions.

Comment: Start by thinking about the definitions of relevant terms... "entire function", "components", "simply connected".

Comment: And how does this conclude that the components are simply connected?